# Convert JSON array value to string

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a JSON array and I got all values from it but I don't see a way to return specific values as array of strings.

```
public class News
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string contentSnippet { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string publishedDate { get; set; }

    public string[] getFeed(string Website)
    {
        string path = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + Website;

        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(path);
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JArray array = (JArray) jsonObject["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"];
        var content = array.Select(token => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(token.ToString())).ToList();

        return new string[] { content.ToString() }; // I thought this could work but it's not.
    }
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft's JSON lib to deserialize it.

If you want to check the JSON file: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=https%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Fpz%3D1%26cf%3Dall%26hl%3Dpt-BR%26output%3Drss

The tool I'm using to visualize better the structure: http://jsonschema.net/#/

Comment: "but it's not" doesn't tell us anything about the difference between what you expected to see and what you're actually seeing. As such, we can't help you. Why are you returning a string array if you actually want to return a single string? (And I'd recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: What is the type of `content` ? You can find by using `content.GetType().Name`

Comment: content looks like a List of News - maybe you need to `content.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray()`

Comment: @Shaharyar it's a list

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, it returned me 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[News_Feed.News]' and I was expecting the values.

Comment: the variable "json" contains your string value why not return that?

Comment: @Oluwafemi doing by this way I just get the JSON file as string, I want only the values.

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes: So what do you *want* the method to return? In your post you said "I don't see a way to return them as string" but now you're saying you want the values. Until you've decided what you want to achieve, we can't possibly help you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by @Shaharyar.

```
public class News
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string contentSnippet { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string publishedDate { get; set; }

    public List<News> getFeed(string Website)
    {
        string path = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + Website;

        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(path);
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JArray array = (JArray) jsonObject["responseData"]["feed"]["entries"];

        var content = array.Select(token => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(token.ToString())).ToList();

        return content;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have created a proper `News` class, why are you returning an string array? You should return an array of `News` type or List of `News` type. Just a suggestion !

Comment: You're now ignoring all but the first item. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually not, I'm trying a way to get the others.

Comment: @Shaharyar returning as `News` I can't get what is in it as string, can I? I wanna show it in a richTextBox.

Comment: Yes you can by serializing `List<News>`

Comment: You can check using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`. also, ternary operator to write precise code

Comment: @Shaharyar I've tried something like `return new List<News> { data };` but I'm still receiving only the first.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you suggest?

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes: I suggest you update your question with what you're hoping to get back from the method - and tell us why you're returning a string array when you *describe* the method as returning a string.

Comment: return `content`, and change return type to `List<news>`